# Lists in Python - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'coeffs'

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have problem with list in python.

here is the simple codes:

```
x = [scipy.poly1d([ 1.,  0.,  0.]),2,3,4,5,'foward']
for i in range (len(x)) :
    if x [i] == 'foward':
        print 'check!'
```

when it's run it will say:

> return NX.alltrue(self.coeffs == other.coeffs)
>   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'coeffs'

but when i change the x into :

```
  x = [1,2,3,4,5,'foward']
```

the program will run no problem.

is there someone could explain to me why? and what should i do? actually i have a fix list of data (x) which return attribute error like above and i don't want to change the format of it and what its contain.

Comment: You ought to format the code correctly. Your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if isinstance(x[i], basestring) and x[i] == 'forward'
```

or quick-and-dirty:

```
if str(x[i]) == 'forward'
```

---

You should also use the `for .. in` loop to iterate over the list:

```
for elem in x:
    if isinstance(elem, basestring) and elem == 'forward':
        print 'Check'
```

If you need `i`, too:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(x):
```

Comment: I like the casting to a string before the comparison (+1).  Using `isinstance` I don't like quite as much ... (although still a completely valid answer)

Comment: Well, you can never know if `str()` on some object might be expensive. Especially with a possibly large mathematical object this is not a too far-fetched possibility.

Comment: Yeah, but you also never know if a non-string object overrides `__eq__` such that it could return `True` for that test ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the equality check that is giving you the problem is in `scipy.poly1d`.  the class probably defines equality checking by comparing the two "polynomial"s coefficients.  Since the string "forward" does not have a coeff attribute, you get an error.

a simple fix would be to put the if statement in a try/except block:

```
try:
   if x[i] == 'forward':
      print 'check'
except AttributeError:
   pass
```

One other thing -- generally doing:

```
for i in range(len(obj)): 
    x=obj[i]
    ...
```

is not the best idiom to use.  A better idiom is:

```
for i,x in enumerate(obj):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if 'foward' is in the list, you can also use

```
if 'foward' in [i for i in x if isinstance(i, basestring)]:
    print 'check'
```